# how to apply command to nth column?

Tags: linux, bash, awk

My input -

```
NY2004 2147483647
NY2009 2147483647
NY2012 2147483647
NY2091 2147483647
NY2205 2147483647
```

I want to apply below command to 2nd column

```
bpdbm -ctime 2147483647
2147483647 = Mon Jan 18 22:14:07 2038
```

I need o/p like this -

```
NY2004 Jan 18  2038
NY2009 Jan 18  2038
NY2012 Jan 18  2038
NY2091 Jan 18  2038
NY2205 Jan 18  2038
```

Comment: `awk '{print $2}' Input.txt | xargs -I {} bpdbm -ctime {}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read col1 col2
do     
     output=$(bpdbm -ctime $col2)
     printf "$col1 %s\n" "$output"
done < input.txt
```

Comment: @user3016638 yes..see merlin2011 comment.